# Is there a way to identify a specific firing instance of a CronTrigger ahead of time?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Say I want to add a note to a specific future firing of a CronTrigger in Quartz.

Is it possible to identify a specific future firing in such a way that I can give other objects a reference to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add "notes" to a trigger's `JobDataMap`. When the trigger fires, those notes can guide that particular occurrence of the job to do something special.

What do you mean by "identify a specific future firing in such a way that I can give other objects a reference to it?" Are you trying to give the job a reference to some object that was available at when the trigger was added?  If its not an object that can be persisted in the `JobDataMap`, you can store its name instead, and use a name service (JNDI, a `getBean` call into Spring, or whatever is appropriate for your environment) to get the object.

Comment: Looping over getFireTimeafter(Date) I can figure out that a CronTrigger will fire at a given point in time in the future, several 'firings' ahead. The question is whether there's any way to refer to that future firing right now, I guess. Still figuring the semantics out on this tbh, not sure the Quartz API supports what I'm trying to do.